# Unable to create call adapter rx.Observable<POJO>

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to make a very basic Retrofit/RxJava setup. So I'm trying to consume this API: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

My basic setup is as follows;

My retrofit service:

```
public interface SimpleTestService {
    String endpoint = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

    @GET("/posts")
    Observable<Post> getPosts();
}
```

Creating the service:

```
public class TestAdapter {
   public static SimpleTestService createService() {
       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl("http://wwww.jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
               .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();

       SimpleTestService service = retrofit.create(SimpleTestService.class);
       return service;
   }
}
```

Making my call:

```
SimpleTestService testService = TestAdapter.createService();
    testService.getPosts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Post post) {
                    String text = testText.getText().toString();
                    text += post.getBody();
                    testText.setText(text);
                }
            });
```

When I try to do this, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable<Post>
```

This is weird to me since I do explicitly add the RX call adapter. I also include all of these things in my build.gradle

any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your Post POJO?

Comment: The POJO is a basic class with 3 fields (all strings), a contructor and all getters/setters for the variables. Thats it. The POJO matches the JSON that the API outputs. Do I need to add something specific to the POJO to make this work? @MuraliPrajapati

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Can you tell me the line which is causing the exception?

Comment: When trying to execute the GET, so testService.getPosts() @MuraliPrajapati

Comment: Let me try on my ide.

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati Thanks! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SimpleTask Service to this

```
public interface SimpleTestService {
String endpoint = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

@GET("/posts")
Observable<List<Post>> getPosts();
}
```

Create service by changing the base url

```
    public class TestAdapter {
       public static SimpleTestService createService() {
           Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(SimpleTestService .endpoint)
                   .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();

           SimpleTestService service = retrofit.create(SimpleTestService.class);
           return service;
       }
    }
```

Your call is like

```
SimpleTestService testService = TestAdapter.createService();
testService .getPosts().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<Post>, Observable<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Post> call(List<Post> posts) {
                return Observable.from(posts);
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Observer<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Post post) {
                String text = testText.getText().toString();
                text += post.getBody();
                testText.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Happy to help you.